How to get snapshot from pg_create_logical_replication_slot?
When reading the documentation about the streaming replication protocol, I see that I can get the snapshot name. This seems to be handy to perform synchronisation before starting to stream the replication messages and make sure I have all the data. However, I do not manage to get the snapshot when calling pg_create_logical_replication_slot sql function (and my client does not implement the streaming replication protocol). How can I get this snapshot name to perform the initial synchronisation ?
For the context, I have an append only table and want to use it as some sort of "event producer", using logical replication to build subscription mechanism.

You have to start a logical replication connection:
psql 'dbname=mydb replication=database'

Then you can use the command CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT to create a logical replication slot:
CREATE_REPLICATION_SLOT newslot LOGICAL pgoutput;

 slot_name │ consistent_point │    snapshot_name    │ output_plugin 
═══════════╪══════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════════
 newslot   │ B/3624D670       │ 00000070-00000002-1 │ pgoutput

To create a pg_dump of the database at that snapshot, use the --snapshot option of pg_dump, keeping the replication connection from above open.
The replication slot has to be used for logical replication or decoding.
